# Proof by contradiction for a set question

Tags: elementary-set-theory

I have a statement I need to prove by contradiction:

If $A$ and $B$ are sets then $A \cap (B-A) = \emptyset$.

None of the questions I've ever done for this class are like this so I'm not really sure how to approach this. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: How do you define $A-B$?

Comment: Sorry, I wrote the question wrong, its B-A

Comment: Hint: The way to prove that some set is empty is to assume there is an element in the set, and derive a contradiction. Have you tried doing this yet?

Comment: Take element x from (A intersect (B-A)). than $x\in A$ and $x\in (B-A)$. Which implies $x\in B$ and not $x\in A$. contradiction

Answer (score 3):

Suppose that $A\cap(B-A)\neq\varnothing$. What does it mean?

It means that $A\cap(B-A)$ is not empty. What does it mean?

It means that there is some $a\in A\cap(B-A)$. What does it mean?

I means that $a\in A$ and $a\in B-A$. What does it mean?

Well, you can continue this, and then you reach a contradiction.

(My advice to you is to sit with all the relevant definitions open before you, and play with yourself the role of teacher and student involved in a Socratic method. Keep asking yourself questions, keep finding the answers in the definitions.)

Comment: Reason for downvote?

Comment: I have no idea, par, all the answers and the questions were downvoted roughly at the same time, so probably by the same user. amWhy's answer got upvoted, I didn't care enough to do something about it, and you have deleted yours. By now your question is sort of moot. But thanks for pointing it out. I suspect a particular user, and my guess is that there is no particular reason that can be expressed with a coherent sentence which is not, essentially "Because I felt like it".

Comment: Well, I upvoted your answer. "Because I felt like it."

Answer (score 2):

Proof by contradiction: We assume that $A \cap (B-A)$ is **not** empty.

That is, assume $A\cap (B-A) \neq \varnothing$.

Then there exists an element $a$ such that $a \in A\cap (B-A)$.  So $a \in A$ AND $a \in (B-A).$ So $a \in A$ and $\Big(a \in B$ AND $a \notin A)$. But this is a contradiction, since it cannot be the case that $a\in A$ and $a \notin A$.

Therefore, since the assumption that $A\cap (B-A) \neq \varnothing$ leads to a contradiction, it follows that indeed, $$A\cap (B-A) = \varnothing.$$